# Is it possible a base class gets informed when a method in derived class is called?

Tags: c#, oop, language-agnostic

Consider the following little design:

```
public class Parent
{
  public event EventHandler ParentWentOut;
  public virtual void GoToWork()
  {
     ParentWentOut();
  }
}

public class Mother : Parent
{
   public override void GoToWork()
   {
     // Do some stuff here
     base.GoToWork(); // <- I don't want to write this in any derived class. 
                      //    I want base class's method to be automatically called.
   }
}
```

Is there any mechanism to make `Parent.GoToWork` method implicitly and automatically be called whenever this method finishes in overridden version of the descendants (here `Mother` class) ?

If there is any other language than C# able to do so, I'll be very thankful to know.

Comment: @roryap Opps ;) Nice catch

Comment: @roryap No worries. I get used to these types of reactions

Comment: out of interest, why don't you want to call base.whatever()?

Comment: @Jay Because a developer may forget to call it. If too many derived types it become a repeated line. Do you think it's not sensible?

Comment: I see. Honestly, I'd just trust the dev to call the right functions. I get the repeated line point, guess it depends if any of the solutions provided are neater. My thoughts would be they probably won't be. If it was my code, I'd just call base.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to implement something like this

```
public class Parent
{
   public event EventHandler ParentWentOut;
   public void GoToWork()
   {
     BeforeParentWentOut();
     ParentWentOut();
     AfterParentWentOut();         
   }

   protected virtual void BeforeParentWentOut()
   {
      // Dont do anything, you can even make it abstract if it suits you
   }

   protected virtual void AfterParentWentOut()
   {
      // Dont do anything, you can even make it abstract if it suits you
   }
}



public class Mother : Parent
{
   protected override void BeforeParentWentOut()
   {
      // Do some stuff here
   }
}
```

Also you can subscribe to your own event on the Mother class and react to that.

EDIT: update for protected, added before/after methods to handle when to add code to the parent implementation

Comment: Its a terrible/bad practice. Makes the code hard to read and reduces maintanability.(kind of hard code).

Comment: No, this *nearly* looks good - but you should make `SpecificMethodForChild` protected instead, so it can't be called from the outside. At that point, this is basically the [template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern), which is absolutely fine IMO. And of course you'd want to document it carefully...

Comment: Normally the overridable method would be `protected`, not `public`, so that it's clear that its not for external users to invoke directly.

Comment: Guys, why don't you even notice that in this solution `base.GoToWork` never gets called?

Comment: Updated to protected, which makes much more sense as per @JonSkeet comment

Comment: @Hans - the point is that `GoToWork` is *only* implemented on the base method. It's always run, and then *it* decides when to invoke the overridable member.

Comment: @Hans the method GoToWork that would be called is the one on the Parent class, which will do whatever it has to do and the call the implementation of the specific class you are using. Give it a go.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Oh my mistake, Sorry and thanks for clarification

Comment: You want ParentWentOut last in the GoToWork method. OP wants parent method to be called last. Just a minor correction.

Comment: One minor problem that always remains is that anyone can do `public new void GoToWork()` in the derived class. But at some point you really have to ask how much you want to protect developers from themselves. I'd just document that the base implementation has to be called an be done with it. If a developer wants to shoot their foot they can always do so.

Answer (score 1):

So, far the only way to access the base class is through the base keyword which some how hold a reference to base class which is initialized by calling its constructor.

Thus your answer is no.

Comment: Any language capable of this?

Comment: I havent seen any language to support what want just yet.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having two methods - one for the public API and one for the internal functioning of the method.

```
public class Parent
{
  public event EventHandler ParentWentOut;
  public void GoToWork()
  {
     GoToWorkOverride();
     ParentWentOut();
  }

  protected virtual void GoToWorkOverride()
  {}
}

public class Mother : Parent
{
   protected override void GoToWorkOverride()
   {
       // Do some stuff here
   }
}
```

Comment: This is the same as Juan's answer from 11 minutes ago

Comment: His was edited to correctness based on @Jon Skeet's suggestion. Mine was right from the start i.t.o public base method calling protected virtual method (template method pattern).